# Let $f$ be an entire function which takes every value no more than three times. What can it be?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f$ be an entire function which takes every value no more than
>   three times. What can it be?

Consider the singularity at infinity. If it is removable then $f$ is constant. If it is a pole then $f$ is a polynomial, and it's clear that degree of $f$ is less than or equal to three. Suppose $f$ has an essential singularity at infinity. The Big Picard theorem says that it takes every value except for possibly one (call it $\omega$) in a neighborhood of $\infty$. Let $w\neq \omega$ and take some value $z_1$ where $f(z_1)=w$. Then there is a neighborhood of infinity which does not include $z_1$, and so there must exist another point $z_2$ where $|z_2|>|z_1|$ and $f(z_2)=2$. By induction there must exist a sequence $z_n$ of distinct points with strictly increasing moduli where $f(z_n)=w$, for all $w\neq \omega$.

**Edit:** I suppose I should clarify why the degree of $f$ must be at most three. This should follow from the density of separable polynomials...suppose $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree greater than three. If $f(z)$ is separable, then $f$ takes the value zero at $>3$ distinct points. If $f$ is not separable, then I want to say that there is a constant $b$ such that $f+b$ is separable, and then $f$ takes the value $-b$ at $>3$ distinct points. But I should make this rigorous...after all, separable polys may be dense, but how do we know that a set of inseparable polynomials is not parallel to the subspace spanned by the constant polynomials (so $f+b$ is inseparable for all $b\in \mathbb{C}$)? Any tips for this?

Comment: You have basically proved your $f$ cannot have an essential singularity at $\infty$ and hence is a polynomial of degree one to three. What is your question????

Comment: @achillehui Take a look now...what do you think?

Comment: Are you asking whether your proof is valid or how can it be improved? Betty's answer speak my mind and in a much better and coherent way.

Comment: About the last part, for any polynomial $g$ of degree $n > 0$ and $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$. If
$$\omega \not\in \bigg\{ g(z) : z \in \mathbb{C},\;s.t.\;g'(z) = 0 \bigg\}$$
then $|g^{-1}(\omega)| = n$. Since the set of exceptional $\omega$ is finite. One can be sure if $\deg f > 3 $, then it will take most values more than three times.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you, that is a better way to see it. And yes, the question was a "proof verification", as the tag indicates.

Comment: @achillehui  I didn't quite follow why the degree of the polynomial must be 3 or less.  Would be happy for further explanation.

Comment: @BettyMock Take any polynomial $g(z)$ of degree $n > 1$. For any $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$, counting multiplicity, $g(z) - \omega$ has exactly $n$ roots for $z \in \mathbb{C}$. If $|g^{-1}(\omega)| < n$, then some of the roots are not simple. On those roots, $g'(z) = 0$. Since, $g'(z)$ has at most $n-1$ roots geometrically, there are at most $n-1$ $\omega$ where $|g^{-1}(\omega)| < n$. i.e. with at most $n-1$ exceptions, $g(z)$ takes every value of $\omega$ exactly $n$ times.

Comment: @achille -- got it, thanks for explaining further

Answer (score 1):

First, did you mean there must exist another point $z_2$ ... such that $f(z_2)$ = w?  You said 2.

It looks to me like the proof is correct; however I think it could be written more clearly:

You said if the singularity is a pole then f is a polynomial of degree 3.  Can you explain why it couldn't be a polynomial like p(z) = $(x-1)^3(x-2)?  Is 1 counted as 3 separate values?  Could you reference a theorem?

You took a w for $z_1$; I would have found it easier to follow if you could stated more clearly why w can't be omitted from any closer neighborhood of $\infty$. (I know big Picard does say that, but I have trouble visualizing neighborhoods of $\infty$ -- maybe others do too?)

Obviously if you can find a sequence of longer than 3 such that $f(z_n)$ = w you have a contradiction; so f cannot have an essential singularity at $\infty$.  At that point  it helps if you specifically state that you have a contradiction and what it is; as well as stating that f must look like what? Do you mean a 3rd degree polynomial?  Any old 3rd degree polynomial?  Or as I asked above, could it be a special polynomial of higher degree?

Comment: If I may suggest, a polynomial $p$ of degree $n\leq 3$ cannot take any value $w_0$ at more than three points simply because $p(z)-w_0$ is another polynomial of degree $n$, which has at most $n$ distinct roots.

Comment: @JonathanY.  I was suggesting a higher order polynomial might take on fewer than n values throughout C.  achille explained in his comment above why that can't happen.

Comment: As did I, yes. But we weren't discussing how many values the function evaluates to, but how frequently it evaluates to each distinct value.

Comment: @JonathanY. yes, that's what I meant, but didn't say it very well.  Higher order polynomials takes on a lot a values -- almost all, no?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra tells us that every non-constant polynomial assumes all complex values, yes.